# How do I match a closing bracket in Emacs lisp

Tags: regular-expressions, delimiters

I would think this was really simple. I am trying to match closing delimiters in Emacs Lisp regex. I can match `{}()[` no problem, but I cannot match `]`. I have been using re-builder and have tried `"[\\}\\)\\]]"`, `"[\\}\\)]]"`, `"[\\}\\)\\\]]"`, `"[\\}\\)\\\\]]"`and it still won't match the closing square bracket. The brace and the parenthesis match just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Somehow related: [Emacs Lisp: regular expression for “anything except close square bracket”?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15120909/605276)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the `]` as the first character after the `[` which starts the character class, e.g.

```
[])}]
```

[This is the manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html)